# How to automatically connect/disconnect to WiFi network only if is needed

Tags: networking, networkmanager

Hello everyone I'm user of a metered adsl->WiFi connection trough a captive portal and I want to automatically login/logout from it when its needed or not. I'm able to manually handle the portal with a script but I don't know if its posible to capture the network need or not.
Any advice with this?

Comment: I would stick to the manual method. It is hard to define _If it is needed_ automatically. Say you are running Ubuntu and `unattended_upgrades` kicks in trying to do `an apt-get update`, or your computer decided to check the time with an `ntp` server or your browser decides to connect on its own to send telemetry, even though you are not using it, should you bring the connection up then?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, thanks for your advice, I think on it before post my question, but maybe there is some method to filter de application. Or maybe I can reformulate my issue to send the login/logout when I turn On or Off the network interface. this can be done?

Comment: Yes, maybe rephrase the question (or make a new one), and show what you have done so far. That will make it easier to help you. If possible (no sensitive information for example), include information about the captive portal technology. The more information you provide, the more likely is somebody might come up with something.